# Python Regex : substring date from string

Tags: python, regex

Can someone help me providing correct regex. I want to remove date from a string.

Ex string : `IO_SE_SOURCE_2015-01-30T19_14_59` I want to remove the date part in the string and fetch only **IO_SE_SOURCE** as the result

I am doing this in python using re.sub() def.

So, when I do the below command

```
var=re.sub(regexpattern,repl,"POC_LN_SOURCE_2015-01-30T19_14_59.something")
```

var should contain the value `POC_LN_SOURCE`

-Thanks

Comment: Do you want to capture everything from the beginning of the string up to `_<datetime>`?

Comment: Try `re.sub('([A-Z_]+)_([\d\-T_]+)(.+)','\\1', 'POC_LN_SOURCE_2015-01-30T19_14_59.something')`.

Comment: @AlexHall - Yes. I want capture before(_datetime) to a variable

Comment: @Abdou- I tried. The entire is been captured. I want only POC_LN_SOURCE to be captured.

Comment: That's exactly what the code captures. It returns `POC_LN_SOURCE`. Isn't that what you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for `re.sub`, just capture a group from a match:

```
>>> re.match(r'(.+)_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', 'POC_LN_SOURCE_2015-01-30T19_14_59.something').group(1)
'POC_LN_SOURCE'
```